# Reaching Definitions analysis - is my solution correct

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, rda

I am asked to write the reaching definition for the following code and I am wondering if my solution is correct? am I even on the right track? I truly appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Code:

```
a = 0;
while (a < 100) {
    b = a + 1
    c = c + b
    a = b * 2
}
return c;
```

Step #1: finding blocks and labeling

```
a = 0;             // block 1  | a1

while (a < 100)    // block 2  |

    b = a + 1      // block 3  | b2
    c = c + b                  | c3
    a = b * 2                  | a3

return c;          // block 3  |
```

Step #2: finding GEN and KILL sets for each block

| BLOCK | GEN | KILL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | a3 |
| 2 | ∅ | ∅ |
| 3 | b3, c3, a3 | a1 |
| 4 | ∅ | ∅ |

Step #4: reviewing the algorithm to find IN and OUT sets

```
input: control flow graph CFG = (N, E, Entry, Exit)
// Boundary condition
OUT[Entry] = ∅

// Initialization for an iterative algorithm
For each basic block B other than Entry
OUT[B] = ∅

// iterate
While (changes to any OUT occur) {
  For each basic block B other than Entry {
    in[B] = ∪ (out[p]), for all predecessors p of B
    out[B] = fB(in[B]) // out[B]=gen[B]∪(in[B]-kill[B])
}
```

Step #5 deriving the IN and OUT sets

| BLOCK | GEN | KILL | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENTRY |  |  |  | ∅ |
| 1 | a1 | a3 | ∅ | a1 |
| 2 | ∅ | ∅ | a1 | a1 |
| 3 | b3, c3, a3 | a1 | a1 | b3, c3, a3 |
| 4 | ∅ | ∅ | b3, c3, a3, a1 | b3, c3, a3, a1 |
| EXIT |  |  | b3, c3, a3, a1 | b3, c3, a3, a1 |

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example: [https://engineering.purdue.edu/~milind/ece573/2011spring/ps8-sol.pdf](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Emilind/ece573/2011spring/ps8-sol.pdf)

The code that is analyzed in that example is slightly more complex than yours, but the entire solution is explained in great detail.